# How to get google analytics data using "Simple API key" in C#?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to use simple api key to get Google Analytics data from C#, but I am getting a login required error. Can some one help me how to get Google Analytics data using simple api key without using OAuth or service account type credentials?

Here is the code I have put together so far:

```
public AnalyticsService Service { get; set; }

[ActionName("GetAnalyticsData")]
[HttpGet]
public AnalyticDataPoint GetAnalyticsData()
{
    Service = new AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApplicationName = "TU-SME Dashboard",
            ApiKey = "AIzaSyBfHuyRHd7Dy4Go_zF3ebjnKB4h3ybiJFk",
        });

    AnalyticDataPoint data = new AnalyticDataPoint();

    GaData response = null;
    var request = Service.Data.Ga.Get("ga:3169903", "30daysAgo","yesterday", "ga:sessions");
    response = request.Execute();

    data.ColumnHeaders = response.ColumnHeaders;
    data.Rows.AddRange(response.Rows);            

    return data;
}

public class AnalyticDataPoint
{
    public AnalyticDataPoint()
    {
        Rows = new List<IList<string>>();
    }

    public IList<GaData.ColumnHeadersData> ColumnHeaders { get; set; }
    public List<IList<string>> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

API keys are used for accessing public data.  Public data is data that is not owned by anyone.   Google Books for example searching in YouTube are examples of requests to public data.

Listing the files on my google drive account, accessing the information on my Google analytics account.  Are examples of private user data.

In order to access private user data the owner of that data must first give you permission to access that data though authentication.

Anwser:  You can use Oauth2 or a service account to access private Google analytics data.  You can not use an API key to access Google analytics data.

**Service account authentication: (from comment)**

Take the service account email address from the Google Developer console, we need to give this email address access to our Google Analytics Data. We do that by adding it as we would any other user in the Admin Section of the Google Analytics Website. Add the service account email address as a user at the account level it must be the account level. This will enable your service account access to the Google Analytics account in question. Did I mention it must be at the ACCOUNT Level?

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics}; // view and manage your Google Analytics data

var keyFilePath = @"c:\file.p12" ;    // Downloaded from https://console.developers.google.com
var serviceAccountEmail = "xx@developer.gserviceaccount.com";  // found https://console.developers.google.com

//loading the Key file
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(keyFilePath, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
var credential = new ServiceAccountCredential( new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) {
                                                   Scopes = scopes}.FromCertificate(certificate));
```

Code ripped from my [Google Analytics tutorial series](http://www.daimto.com/googleAnalytics-authentication-csharp/#Service_Account_Authentication) there is an updated version of it here [Google Service Account with Json file](http://www.daimto.com/google-service-accounts-with-json-file/) however it uses the newer version of the Google analytics api (v4) your code is using the older API (v3) you will need to alter it for use with v3.

How to create service account credentials [Google Developer console service account](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-service-account/)

Comment: I need to get google analytics data for my website and show it on dashboard for internal purpose. We are not showing this outside. Can I access it by giving login credentials to google data from c-sharp .net and use api key to access it?

Comment: I recommend you use a service account then.   You cant use login and password (client login) to access any Google APIs.

Comment: I am trying to use service account.and I am the owner of the account, but when I get into Admin and click User Management (the only clickable option, the rest is grayed out), I get the message:

* User Management:  You do not have sufficient permissions to modify the users on this account.

Then of course I cannot do anything in Property column (all grayed out).
Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Figure out who or what account is the owner. The one you are using to login isn't the owner. Only an owner can add new users